# mysqli insert statement not working with phpexcel

Tags: php, mysqli

i am trying to insert data from excel 2007 file into mysql via a web page.i am using phpexcel library and it cant work..help please..my code looks this way:
i have checked every where and most codes are this way the on;y thing is that my database remains empty

```
<?php  
//In case you want the script to be executed at a predefined time interval, use this   
/*header('Refresh: 30'); */

//Establishing connection to Mysql Database:
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","final");   
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {    
echo mysqli_connect_error();     
exit(); } 
//PHPEXCEL Reader
            require 'includes/PHPExcel.php';
            require_once 'includes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
//action that happens when the button is pressed
if (isset($_POST['button1'])) 
        {
                echo "button on is pressed";
                 if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
                {
                        echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . 
            "You have not selected a file or some other error <br />";
                }
                else
                {       //  Errorless  start 
                        $inputFileName=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
                        $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("C:/julisha/uploads/".$inputFileName);   

                                        // Creating a temporary copy on the server 
                                        $location="C:/wamp/www/julisha/uploads/"; // write the location on 
                    // server where a copy should be created
                                        move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
                    $location . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
//$inputFileName    = $file_name;
$inputFileType  = 'Excel2007'; 

$objReader  = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("$inputFileType");
$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

$objWorksheet   = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

$highestRow     = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow();
$highestColumn  = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn();
$highestColumnIndex = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn);
//Display Excel data on webpage
echo '<table>' . "\n";
for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
    echo '<tr>' . "\n";

for ($col = 0; $col <= $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {
    echo '<td>' . $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row)->getValue() . '</td>' . "\n";
}
echo '</tr>' . "\n";    
}
echo '</table>' . "\n";
//Preparing to import data from Excel to Mysql Database:
for($row = 2; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
for($col = 0; $col < $highestColumnIndex; ++$col) {     
$rows[$col] = $objWorksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow($col, $row);

}


$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO temp_results (Adm_No,Engl,Kis,Math,Chem) VALUES ('$rows[0]', '$rows[1]', '$rows[2]', '$rows[3]', '$rows[4]',)");

  }

                }            
}
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

there is a `,` in the end of your query please remove it

change

```
 $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO temp_results (Adm_No,Engl,Kis,Math,Chem) VALUES ('$rows[0]', '$rows[1]', '$rows[2]', '$rows[3]', '$rows[4]',)");
```

with

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO temp_results (Adm_No,Engl,Kis,Math,Chem) VALUES ('$rows[0]', '$rows[1]', '$rows[2]', '$rows[3]', '$rows[4]')");
```